# Что сжигали на Масленицу: куклу или чучело?

Tags: этимология, лексика, выбор-слов, история

Ввиду нынешнего празднования Масленицы возник вопрос. А что именно сжигают, а точнее, сжигали? *Куклу* или *чучело?* Каковы истории образования и первородные смыслы этих слов? Я думаю, что — куклу, так как в ритуалах действовали куклы.

Кто знает, поделитесь и поправьте меня!

Comment: Не вижу принципиальной разницы. Все зависит от понимания слов "кукла" и "чучело". Как Вы-то отличаете одно от другого?

Comment: Кукла этимологически восходит к греческому. Поверю в то, что применять это слово начали к театральным куклам.

Comment: А вот чучело очень интересное слово, но этимологию да и историю в целом не нашёл (честно признаться глубоко-то и не копал). Но я невольно обращаю на построение этого слова - Чу + чело. Чело думаю всем понятно, что такое, а вот с "чу"... Так же как и со словом "чур". Не было ли изначально - чуРчело? только с ударением на "у";)

Answer (score 1):

*Кукла этимологически восходит к греческому.*

Скорее наоборот:

> В рус. языке XI–XVII вв. изв. кuкла в 2 значениях. 
>   ...
>    Вероятнее всего, из лат. cuculla «капюшон, башлык,
>   клобук», заимствования поздней общеславянской эпохи. Позднее **из слав.
>   заимствовано в ср.-греч.** и алб.

**Чучело** появилось намного позже:

> Сущ. чучело изв. в рус. языке с XVIII в., запечная чучела отм. в
>   словаре 1731 г., чучело – с 1771 г. ▲ Из праслав. *чучало,
>   производного с суф. -л- от глаг. *чучати «сидеть на корточках,
>   притаившись; сидеть тихо».

Процитированы (частично) статьи из этимологического словаря А.К. Шапошникова.